# How can I remove the repetitive characters in Histogram [JAVA]

Tags: java, loops, histogram

```
class Mclass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] a= {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c'};
        int count = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
                  for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
                  {
                      if ( a[j] == a[i] )
                          count += 1;
                  }
                  System.out.println(a[i]+":"+count);
                  count = 0;
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

`a:2
b:2
c:2
d:1
a:2
b:2
c:2`

Here I want to stop the loop until it counts d = 1. but it again prints the same variable? How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from what you already did, first sort the array then try to count

```
import java.util.*;
class Mclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a= {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c'};
        int count = 0;
        Arrays.sort(a);  // sort the array
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
          for(int j=i; j<a.length; j++)
          {
              if ( a[j] == a[i] ){
                  count += 1;
                  continue;
              }          
              i=j-1;
              break;
          }
          System.out.println(a[i]+":"+count);
          count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
a:2
b:2
c:2
d:1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to print the character that has already been printed, you need to maintain it somewhere like in a `Set` and print only when `Set` doesn't contain the character and after printing, add it to `Set` so next time on wards it doesn't get printed.

Change your code to this,

```
class Mclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> doneSet = new HashSet<String>();

        char[] a = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c' };
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j] == a[i])
                    count += 1;
            }
            if (!doneSet.contains(String.valueOf(a[i]))) {
                System.out.println(a[i] + ":" + count);
                doneSet.add(String.valueOf(a[i]));
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives following output as you intend,

```
a:2
b:2
c:2
d:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not print inside loop

Save your count and print outside the loop.

Do something like this:

```
public class Mclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] a= {'a','b','c','d','a','b','c'};
    int count = 0;
    Map<String,Integer> output = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
              for(int j=0; j<a.length; j++)
              {
                  if ( a[j] == a[i] )
                      count += 1;
              }
              output.put(Character.toString(a[i]), count);
              //System.out.println(a[i]+":"+count);
              count = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
  }
}
```